# What to do when the accepted answer is a link-only answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer, link-only-answers

Normally when I see a link-only answer I flag and move on. However, what do I do when the answer has already been accepted?

This is the post in question: [Unity How to make GameObject Speed gain velocity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27166985/unity-how-to-make-gameobject-speed-gain-velocity/27168434#27168434)

I haven't flagged the answer nor downvoted it. I did post my own version of it. Any suggestions?

Comment: @BlueMoon: So, you mean link-only answers are ok if they are not link-only answers? Sure thing ;-)

Comment: @BlueMoon: That certainly wasn't offensive. It's just that "link-only is ok if the link is helpful" would mean there is no reason left to flag link-only answers at all.

Comment: One aspect that might not be obvious: If you flag an accepted answer, it goes to a moderator, not to the LQ review queue. And they don't always apply the same criteria.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just because the answer has been accepted doesn't mean it is now exempt from review.

Best approach would be to leave a comment on the answer asking the user to expand their answer to quote the relevant sections within their post and/or downvote it if you feel that is necessary. Answers with a score of -1 or lower can be [given delete votes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) by trusted users (20,000 reputation).

Link-only answers are all well and good in the present. But a couple of months down the line the page linked to may no longer exist or may have been heavily modified in a way which makes it no longer answer the question.

The Help Center's Answering section has an article titled [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing), which states:

> When you find a useful resource that can help answer a question (from another site or in an answer on Stack Overflow) make sure you do all of the following:
>
> - Provide a link to the original page or answer
> - Quote only the relevant portion
> - Provide the name of the original author

...perhaps the word "all" there should be emphasised to make it stand out more.

Comment: Have you ever tried deleting an accepted answer? Any success yet?

Comment: @Deduplicator: I have never understood why **Trusted** User**s** would not be allowed to delete them. It is a shame.

Comment: @Deduplicator yes I have. The one linked to in this question, in fact: http://i.imgur.com/R9YTQfS.png.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: ah, no, I remembered the restrictions wrong. You cannot *self-delete* when the answer is marked as accepted; 10k users can still vote to delete regardless of the accepted status. Sorry.

Comment: @lpapp: trusted users **are** allowed to deleted them, as long as it is *not their own post*.

Comment: @Deduplicator: 10k+ users can vote to delete accepted answers, provided they are at -1 or below. You just cannot delete your *own* accepted answers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I have more than 10k. Just went to the main-site and looked for accepted answers with score of -10 or below. The first one gives me these options: `share edit flag` missing: `delete`. http://i.stack.imgur.com/z1tfe.png

Comment: @Deduplicator: every one of [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?page=305&tab=votes&q=isaccepted%3ayes%20score%3a..-1%20is%3aa) have `delete` links. That's the most-downvoted accepted answers list. [This example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7942368) has an actual delete vote on it.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Ah! There's the rub. I misspoke then. But lpapp used the term 'Trusted User' which is the 20k privilege.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: erm, correction, 20k users, aka [Trusted Users](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user).

Comment: @Deduplicator: You cannot vote to delete *any* answer other than your own, not accepted, not anything else.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: that was actually deleted by a moderator, not necessarily by you. Can you give an example where an accepted answer was deleted by TUs only without moderator or CM intervention? Although it is kind of hard to prove without going through the process because when it is deleted, there is no marker that it was accepted, or maybe there is, I am just not aware of it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: then I do not understand why people kept repeating the mantra of not being able. Perhaps I should not trust people if that is true.

Comment: "*Link-only answers are all well and good in the present. But a couple of months down the line the page linked to may no longer exist*". That argument is a bit overused here, I think. Links change, that's just the way the web works in general. I understand the general idea, but if you look at that particular link, it's on the official Q&A site of the framework in the question, so on balance, it's likely to be stable. If it went down, it would be likely that the framework has disappeared (or changed fundamentally), which would in turn make the overall question hard to follow anyway.

Comment: @Bruno: Lot's of documentation-writers absolutely don't get the idea that URLs should stay stable. You cannot actually generalize that a change in the URL in any way means changed info. Let alone signals a significant change.

Comment: @Deduplicator Indeed. I'm certainly not saying that a change in URL means changed info. I wasn't talking at all about that implication at all, rather the other way: assuming a link is necessarily bad because it will "decay" one way or another (which is the reasoning behind the link-only answer hunt) is also often exaggerated, especially when that links is on the domain of the framework in question. Of course, link-only answers with just a link to some random 3rd-party site (typically some blog) are terrible.

Comment: @Bruno Even if the site remains, that's no guarantee that that *particular* URL will remain. As Deduplicator mentions, many website owners don't consider that links to their content exist outside of their system, and will change URLs willy-nilly and break those links. But even if it the link remains, link-only answers suck because they effectively turn Stack Overflow into a crowd-sourced Google, so I'm fine with any argument that makes them go away.

Comment: @ChrisHayes I've edited my answer to elaborate a bit more on this. Link-only answers are indeed terrible, when they are pure link-only, but often there's a little bit more to it than that. Even link-only answers don't turn SO into a crowd-sourced Google: you still have the ability to vote, comment, add additional answers. There's still far more to it than a search engine that can interpret your question.

Comment: @ChrisHayes I would also add that even if both site and URL remain, that's no guarantee that _content_ will. I broke my nose on this at least once and it was... no fun (Wikipedia article changed in a way that invalidated referencing it in the context of a particular answer)

Comment: @gnat That's a bit of a far-fetched argument too. By that standard, you wouldn't link to any other content on Stack Exchange either, since it can be edited later.

Comment: @Bruno nope, by this standard you better provide in the post a summary of what you see at the link. This way, important stuff will survive even if link or its content goes away (and also will allow readers looking for past content in Wayback Machine or, if we speak about Wikipedia, in article revisions history)

Answer (score 6):

To be fair, this was *not* a link-only answer (credit to [its author](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3232112/rahul-singh)):

> Please follow the link below.
>   http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/224693/add-force-increase-speed-of-ball-periodically.html
>
> It explains about Adding Force to Increase the Speed of Ball. This
>   might help you with your torpedo speed.

While most of the information might indeed be in the document linked, the answer itself suggests "*Adding Force to Increase the Speed of Ball*". It may be very succinct indeed, but it may also be sufficient for the readers to solve their problems, or at least to point them in the right direction, even if the link was down.

For that reason, it shouldn't have been deleted as a link-only answer. Of course, that certainly doesn't mean it was a good answer that deserved upvotes.

---

In fact, had this answered be phrased slightly differently, as follows, it probably wouldn't have been flagged:

> You could try adding force to increase the speed of your torpedo, as described in [this example](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/224693/add-force-increase-speed-of-ball-periodically.html).

(Flagging it as a link-only answer effectively penalises an answerer who was willing to help for not knowing his Markdown syntax very well, for one of his first answers on the site.)

---

Coming back to the controversial topic of link-only answers, they're generally bad indeed, but not all links are equal. Taking too hard a stance on answers that look like link-only answers (but often actually have a tiny bit more information) doesn't help anyone. And *yes*, we're here to help. Many people (especially on Meta) seem to think that the only goal of Stack Overflow is to build a knowledge repository, not a to be a help site, but at the end of the day, the aim of that knowledge repository is to help its readers. Curating in an unnecessarily harsh way can actually hinder that objective.

The question in question now has a better answer, so this point is a bit irrelevant, but when the now-deleted "link-only" answer was the only answer, this was a decent pointer (it was even briefly selected as the accepted answer).

If no new answer had been written, it could very well have stayed for a long period of time, helping any reader having the same question.

Maybe the "link decay" issue would have become a problem at some point in time, but that's just the way the web works. For corner cases like this (again, not strictly a link-only answer), a bit of judgement could be used, instead of deleting such a "suspicious" answer on the spot.

In particular, the domain name of that link is the official domain associated with the framework in the question. Sure, there's never any absolute certainty, and document writers may indeed move their links around from time to time, but it is reasonable to assume that this link is going to be reasonably maintained, at least that its fate is going to be closely linked to that of the framework in question. (If `unity3d.com` completely disappeared, questions about Unity 3D would also probably be completely irrelevant.)

I'm not suggesting that we should keep link-only answers in any case, let alone that we should consider them to be good answers. I'm suggesting that we use a bit more judgement before flagging and deleting such answers, by considering these answers in their context, and assessing the balance between providing useful information to the reader against the risk the link might no longer work on day in the future. (If we assume that the world around Stack Overflow is going to disappear, we're in serious trouble anyway.)

A typical example of terrible link-only answer that should indeed be deleted would be:

> Try this: `http://myblog.dyndns.example/...`

However, there is a major difference with this and what we had in the deleted answer:

- The answer mentioned "adding force" (and if we look at the now-accepted answer, it relies on an `AddForce` method, so that would have been a useful clue to look for, even in an offline copy of the framework's documentation).
- The link was reasonably likely to be stable. Sure there's always a risk, but in doubt, for edge cases like this, trying to not to prevent users helping each other is often a better choice.

Answer (score 3):

This is how external sources should be used according to the help-center:

> When you find a useful resource that can help answer a question (from another site or in an answer on Stack Overflow) make sure you do all of the following:
>
> - Provide a link to the original page or answer
> - Quote only the relevant portion
> - Provide the name of the original author

Due to failure to provide anything but the link, the answer is a link-only-answer, and should be flagged and deleted as such.
Though consider also downvoting and/or commenting, both to make sure your flag is properly acted on and to give the poster a heads-up so he might get his act together faster (or at all).

Be wary of applying the same to old posts, as moderation is far more lenient on them (unless they obviously only have content already incorporated into proper answers).
Remember: The primary tenant of moderation is not doing harm, and simply removing info normally contravenes that.
(Deletion of new posts often triggers correction, while deletion of old ones is hardly noted.)