# Non-moderator can delete accepted answer

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, accepted-answer, vote-to-delete

I've just deleted an accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40136965/674039).  The last time I checked my username it was still `wim` and not `wim ♦`.

Is that a bug?

Comment: If it is, it's not a new one. In the comment thread on [this answer from 2014](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277977/5067311) Martijn explains that trusted users *can* delete-vote accepted answers.

Comment: Hmm.  [Well, the history doesn't lie](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40137123/timeline); I don't see an unaccept anywhere in there.  Even so, I find this to be *amazing*, since it means that bad content can't be protected by it being accepted.

Comment: @yellowantphil:  Was there any history in that timeline that indicated that you had *accepted* it in the first place?  It may be that the unaccept event is the removal of the accept event.

Comment: Based on context of that question and answer and OP, I can assure you that the answer must have been accepted still when it got deleted. (cc @yellowantphil)

Comment: @yellowantphil I was following that question throughout the day and was on the page when the answer got closed, and the accept was never removed prior.

Comment: This is a bug as well as a feature.

Comment: So you deleted it on a wim?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

So... Funny story...

The change referenced in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83356/20k-users-can-vote-to-delete-negatively-voted-accepted-answers/83359#83359) that [Andras](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336594/non-moderator-can-delete-accepted-answer/336595#336595) dug up?

It didn't actually do anything. Ever. The check was added in the wrong spot; it effectively stops trusted users from being able to delete closed questions for two days after they've been closed, *if those closed questions also happen to be accepted answers.* Which, of course, they never are.

So this was never actually disallowed.

At some point, folks noticed this (I vaguely remember it coming up during the review re-write in 2012 since we thought we might have to allow it), but since it didn't seem to be causing any problems, no one did anything about it.

Funny enough, the FAQ didn't mention the restriction *at all* until this spring - probably because most of that FAQ is based on folks' observations. I've reverted that assertion now.

Comment: So the author can't delete an own answer when it's accepted, but a trusted user can vote to delete -1 accepted answer. What if the author of that answer is a trusted user, will be able to cast a delete vote?

Comment: Nope, @Oriol - which hints that we may wish to revisit *that* particular restriction at some point, if only to give parity to authors and trusted users.

Comment: Ironic that an author can vote to delete someone else's accepted answer but not their own.  Probably was a protection against ragequit abuse, but if the answer has negative score then it really shouldn't apply.

Comment: IMO, they should be able to vote-to-delete... seems a fair compromise

Answer (score 10):

I found [a comment thread on an answer from 2014](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277977/5067311) wherein Martijn Pieters explains that trusted users *can* delete-vote accepted answers.

But here's the catch: [the relevant community FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) says

> 5. Users with reputation ≥ 20k (more precisely, the trusted-user privilege; 4k on beta sites) are not subject to the 48-hour waiting period for deleting closed questions with a score of −3 or lower. They may also delete answers of score −1 or lower, **unless they are accepted**. It takes three votes to delete an answer.

(emphasis mine). There's also a [link to a post from 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83356/20k-users-can-vote-to-delete-negatively-voted-accepted-answers/83359#83359) which explicitly states that delete-voting accepted answers became forbidden in March, 2011:

> Though nothing will break, I went ahead and disallowed this. If you want an accepted answer deleted, flag it for moderator attention.

I suspect that it has been restored in the mean time, buried somewhere on meta. If this is the case, then the community FAQ should be updated. If this is *not* the case, then the bug should be fixed.

Comment: I remain steadfast in believing that this is a **feature**.

Comment: [bug or feature?](http://globalnerdy.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2007/12/bug_vs_feature.gif)

Comment: @Makoto let's hope so. I expect this *feature* to be much more useful than the potential harm it could cause. Trusted users are trusted for a reason, and unduly deleted accepted answers can transparently be accounted for.