# Totally changing an accepted answer

Tags: discussion, edits, rollbacks

I just came across an edit on an Accepted Answer that totally has changed it

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3045043/revisions

I don't disagree with the new answer, however I though that totally changing what the original author of an answer said was not acceptable.

Should these edits be rolled back?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is totally inappropriate for an editor to completely change the content of someone else's answer like that. The edits should be reverted. If the editor wants to make that content available, they can post their own answer.

Answer (score 1):

While one should not be making such edit I don't think rolling back is a good solution in all cases.

To take appropriate action on the post you should check history and see what versions of the post got votes. If positive votes collected on  updated version reverting will provide wrong guidance on quality of the answer. I.e. in case of linked question https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3045043/timeline shows that original version got all votes - feel free to roll back.

Now rollback may delete quality content (like in this case). To preserve content consider adding new answer with that content (possibly as CW).

Another consideration - whether rollback makes answer incorrect, especially in case of accepted answer. While edit is inappropriate it may be beneficial for the site to keep updated version rather than incorrect one. Alternative (delete post) is often not viable due to potentially large number of votes needed (only answers with score -1 can be deleted by non-admins - [What to do when the accepted answer is a link-only answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277974/what-to-do-when-the-accepted-answer-is-a-link-only-answer/277977#277977)).

Note that in case of particular question "what is ... most popular name ..." may be closed as "opinion based" instead.

Comment: I've have created a CW answer.  Most of the votes were from before it was edited, so in this case the Rollback was justified I believe.  And yes, I had already voted to close as opinion based before you posted your answer :-)